# Auto-submit django form without causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

I have an issue on my app that I can't work out the best way to approach the solution. I'm learning Django and have little to no experience in Javascript so any help will be appreciated. This may be a design flaw, so am open to other ideas.

**Problem**
When a user reaches their dashboard page for the first time, they would need to select the currency rate on a form they want to view their data in e.g USD, AUD, GBP etc. Once they submit their currency, their dashboard will become active and viewable. I would like this selection to remain submitted on refresh/load or auto submit on refresh/load. Hence, that currency will remain, unless the user submits another currency.

See before/after images for context (ignore values as they are inaccurate):

[image: Before/After user submits currency]

**Attempted solution**
I have tried using Javascript to auto submit on load which causes and infinite loop.
I have read to use `action` to redirect to another page but i need it to stay on the same page.
Unless this can be configured to only submit once after refresh/load I don't think this will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.document.forms['currency_choice'].submit();
  });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>
    <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        </span>
        <span>
        <form method="post" name="currency_choice">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form_c.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**FORM**

```
class CurrencyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=currencies, label='Choose Currency:',)

    class Meta:
        model = UserCurrency
        fields = (
            'currency',
        )
```

**MODEL**

```
class UserCurrency(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**VIEW**

```
class MyDashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        form_c = CurrencyForm(prefix='form_c')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form_c': form_c,
        })

    def post(self, request):

        currency = None

        form_c = CurrencyForm(request.POST, prefix='form_c')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form_c.is_valid():
                cur = UserCurrency.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
                cur.delete()
                post = form_c.save(commit=False)
                post.user = request.user  # Registers the entry by the current user
                post.save()
                currency = UserCurrency.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values('currency')
                currency = currency[0]['currency']
        else:
            form_c = CurrencyForm()

        rates = {'USD': 1.0, 'AUD': 1.321, 'GBP': 0.764, 'CAD': 1.249}

        deposit = 10000 / rates[currency]

        context = {
            'currency': currency,
            'deposit': dep,
            'form_c': form_c,
        }

        return render(request, 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a default currency on initialization instead of requiring a submit? Otherwise to prevent the infinite loop you need to set some flag to indicate the initialization has already happened, perhaps in `localStorage`.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on your suggestion? I haven't had experience with this problem yet. I am unsure how to initialize the form without submitting

Comment: What is the interaction that you imagine your user should have when using this form?
Should they input some data into the form and then click some kind of save-button?
Should they not have to click some kind of save-button, but rather have their inputs saved automatically?

Answer (score 1):

make a new temporary template with this only content, make a view to render and add view caller in your `urls.py`

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_c.as_p }}
```

update your current template and insert ajax (i am assuming you have idea of jquery ajax)

```
<form method="post" name="currency_choice">
    <div id="currency-choice">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form_c.as_p }}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$( "#btn-submit" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url : '{% url 'url-of-new-template' %}', 
       success : function(response){ 
           $('#currency-choice').html(response)
       },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. The form you've provided does not render the form. When I remove the ```<div>``` tag it's ok but I'm assuming the ```id``` is needed.

Also, here is my view and url: #view ```
def temp_view(request):
    return render(request, 'coinprices/url-of-new-template.html')
```
# url
path('my-deposits/currency', temp_view, name='url-of-new-template'),
```

Also, the ```url-of-new-template``` just contains ```{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_c.as_p }}```.

Would you mind elaborating what is happening here? I don't understand what the approach is. Thanks

Comment: i just edited my answer. btw what i understand by your question is, you dont want to submit your form when click on submit. so wht iam doing is i am replacing a new form when clicking to submit without loading page

Answer (score 1):

The general practice for this type of situation is to only use the `post` method for validating and saving the submission, and then automatically reloading the page.

Javascript isn't required, so you can remove it from your template.

I have modified your `UserCurrency` model to use a `OneToOneField` relationship with the `User`. This means that there can be no more than one of these records per `User`. It also means that you can access the saved currency directly from the user instance.

I have also set a default currency of 'USD'. In the view, the `try`/`except` block creates a temporary `UserCurrency` instance when one doesn't already exist.

**MODEL**

```
class UserCurrency(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name="user_currency",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="USD")
```

**VIEW**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MyDashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Add the saved currency, deposit and form to the context. 
        This is then available for both get and post methods.

        """
        try:
            user_currency = self.request.user.user_currency
        except UserCurrency.DoesNotExist:
            user_currency = UserCurrency(user=self.request.user)
        
        rates = {'USD': 1.0, 'AUD': 1.321, 'GBP': 0.764, 'CAD': 1.249}

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_currency'] = user_currency
        context['deposit'] = 10000 / rates[user_currency.currency]
        context['form_c'] = CurrencyForm(instance=user_currency, prefix='form_c')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        If valid, save/update the model instance and reload the page.
        Otherwise, display the form with errors.

        """
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form_c = CurrencyForm(request.POST, instance=context['user_currency'], prefix='form_c')
        
        if form_c.is_valid():
            form_c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

        context['form_c'] = form_c
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```